How to read reply message from QDBus
i have two application, first application send QDbus message, second - read this message and send reply. How i can read reply message in second application?
example with d-send is ok, i read from console reply string.
constructor:
DBus::DBus(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    new DBusAdaptor(this);
    QDBusConnection::sessionBus().registerService(SERVICE_NAME);
    QDBusConnection::sessionBus().registerObject(SERVICE_PATH, this);
    iface = new org::example::dbus(QString(), SERVICE_PATH, QDBusConnection::sessionBus(), this);
}

function:
void DBus::sendRequest()
{
// send request to first application
    QDBusMessage msg = QDBusMessage::createSignal(SERVICE_PATH, SERVICE_NAME, "sendRequest");
    QDBusConnection::sessionBus().send(msg);
}

